# Reduce columns of dataframe by creating a new column

Tags: r

I have a survey of a few dozen questions which I need to analyse with R. Each question can accept 2 answers, and the following question is directly related to the former one. Every question .a can accept only YES/NO as an Answer, every question .b can only accept Danger/No Danger as an answer. It is organised like this :

| Question 1.a | Question 1.b | Question 2.a | Question 2.b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | No Danger | No | Danger |
| Yes | Danger | Yes | Danger |

As you can see, all questions .a share the same type of answers, all questions .b share the same type of answers.

I would like to reorganise my dataframe for it to look like this:

| Question | Part a | Part b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | No Danger |
| 1 | Yes | Danger |
| 2 | No | Danger |
| 2 | Yes | Danger |

How can I do that? I tried pivots but it is not giving the output I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Tidyr's `pivot_longer()` can do this:

```r
x <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Question.1.a, ~Question.1.b, ~Question.2.a, ~Question.2.b,
          "Yes",   "No Danger",          "No",      "Danger",
          "Yes",      "Danger",         "Yes",      "Danger"
)

x |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c("Question", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "Question.(1|2)\\.(a|b)"
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   Question a     b        
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>    
#> 1 1        Yes   No Danger
#> 2 2        No    Danger   
#> 3 1        Yes   Danger   
#> 4 2        Yes   Danger
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here a less elegant solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Your data
df = data.frame("Q1.A" = c("Yes", "Yes"),
                "Q1.B" = c("No Danger", "Danger"),
                "Q2.A" = c("No", "Yes"),
                "Q2.B" = c("Danger", "Danger"))

# Gathering Answer A
df_1 = df %>% 
  gather(key="Question", value="Answer A", contains("A")) %>%
  mutate(Question = substring(Question, 1,2)) %>%
  select(Question, "Answer A")

# Gathering Answer B
df_2 = df %>% 
  gather(key="Question", value="Answer B", contains("B")) %>%
  mutate(Question = substring(Question, 1,2)) %>%
  select(Question, "Answer B")

# Binding column
cbind(df_1, df_2['Answer B'])

      Question Answer A  Answer B
1       Q1      Yes No Danger
2       Q1      Yes    Danger
3       Q2       No    Danger
4       Q2      Yes    Danger
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Your data
df = data.frame("Q1.A" = c("Yes", "Yes"),
                "Q1.B" = c("No Danger", "Danger"),
                "Q2.A" = c("No", "Yes"),
                "Q2.B" = c("Danger", "Danger"))

# Transforms
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% # Adding row-number for unique rows
  pivot_longer(-row) %>% # Making long format
  separate(name, into = c("Q", "A_B"), sep = "\\.") %>% # Separating Q.A by dot
  pivot_wider(names_from = A_B, values_from = value) %>% # Making wide again
  select(Q, A, B)

  Q     A     B        
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    
1 Q1    Yes   No Danger
2 Q2    No    Danger   
3 Q1    Yes   Danger   
4 Q2    Yes   Danger
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reshape`

```
> reshape(dat, varying=1:4, direction='long', sep='.', timevar='Question',
+         v.names=paste('Part', unique(regmatches(names(dat), regexpr('.$', names(dat))))),
+          new.row.names=1:1e9) |> subset(select=-id)
  Question Part a    Part b
1        1    Yes No Danger
2        1    Yes    Danger
3        2     No    Danger
4        2    Yes    Danger
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Question.1.a = c("Yes", "Yes"), Question.1.b = c("No Danger", 
"Danger"), Question.2.a = c("No", "Yes"), Question.2.b = c("Danger", 
"Danger")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```